# How to put a whole html page in a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

First of all I want everyone to know that I am absolute beginner so please be patient with me.

I want to know how am I going to put the entire html page in a div. I tried `$("#footballPlayers").html("footballplayers.html");` but it displays `footballplayers.html` text instead of the whole page.

#### index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $("div#tabFootballPlayers").click(function(){
    $("#footballPlayers").html("footballplayers.html");
    $("#actionStars").html("");
    $("#directors").html("");
  });
 });

 $(function(){
  $("div#tabActionStars").click(function(){
   $("#actionStars").html("actionstars.html");
   $("#footballPlayers").html("");
   $("#directors").html("");
  });
 });

 $(function(){
  $("div#tabDirectors").click(function(){
   $("#directors").html("directors.html");
   $("#actionStars").html("");
   $("#footballPlayers").html("");
  });
 });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <div id="tabFootballPlayers">Football Players</div>
 <div id="footballPlayers"> </div>
 <div id="tabActionStars">Action Stars</div>
 <div id="actionStars"> </div>
 <div id="tabDirectors">Directors</div>
 <div id="directors"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want the entire thing in a div?  That isn't valid.

Comment: MGZero, you are wrong! There are many benefits of using that logic (entire page on a div). You have no idea how it opens the possibilites. ... AND IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Oliver really ? its 2011 you know ....

Comment: @ManseUK Sure, I wouldn't do anything like this at all. But if I had to, I'd use iframes.

Comment: @Oliver if you wouldnt do it then dont suggest it to someone learning ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use load

```
jQuery("#footballPlayers").load("footballplayers.html");
```

for more details [click here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 9):

You use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$("#footballPlayers").load('footballplayers.html body');
```

Notice the selector after the URL. You can select elements from that page. I think you need the `body`, as having nested `<html>` tags could end badly.

---

A few more comments about your code:

You don't use this function more than once. Just shove all of your code into it:

```
$(function() {
  // All of your code here.
});
```

I prefer this syntax, as it looks more functional and shows you what it does:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // All of your code here.
});
```

Also, your code is really redundant. Try condensing it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#your_menu_container div").click(function() {
    $(this).load(this.id.substr(3).toLowerCase() + '.html').siblings().html('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

replace

```
$("#directors").html("directors.html");
```

with

```
$("#directors").load("directors.html");
```

**the html file that you load should only contain the contents of the DIV - ie not the `<head>` the `<body>` or even the navigation - just the content**

Comment: Or you could use a selector and load just the body: `.load("directors.html body");`

Comment: @Blender yep - but maybe not body if the page is the same as in the question but with the div completed .... thats why i pointed the OP towards making the HTML file just the contents

Answer (score 6):

You can use `load` for this:

```
$("#div1").load("myhtmlpage.htm");
```

Answer (score 4):

TRY:

```
$("#footballPlayers").load("footballplayers.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually load the contents of `footballplayers.html` using AJAX, and then put that in the div.

Try this:

```
$("#footballPlayers").load("footballplayers.html");
```

`.load` uses AJAX to get the page, then loads it into the div.

Answer (score 2):

using your code you fill the html code with a constant string "footballplayer.html".

You can use the load method, here is an example:

```
$('#footballPlayers').load('footballplayers.html');
```

it get via AJAX the page you request and fill the element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the `load` train:

```
$("#div1").load("myhtmlpage.htm");
```