# How to load whole page into a div when clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please, some help would be truly appreciated.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155932/how-to-put-a-whole-html-page-in-a-div-using-jquery) and I think i understood the answers

The thing is, I want the other page to be injected into the "main" div when a link is clicked. For example, when I click 2011, I want the page 2011.html to be injected into the "main" div.

```
    <div id="cssmenu" class="sixteen columns">
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>2011</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>2012</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>2013</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Edições Especiais</span></a></li>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Estat&iacute;sticas</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="separator" class="sixteen columns">
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen columns" id="main" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px">

    </div>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer on the question you pointed?

Comment: Yes, @Sergio, but i can't figure out how to do this by demand, like when clicking a link.

Comment: It's better to add a valid `href` attribute to the links. Search engines will be able to follow the links too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).find('span').text();
    $("#main").load(name + ".html");
});
```

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uX7x5/)

This is a idea for 2011 - 2013 pages, but the ones with name wont work. You need to either give a id to the `a` element or a `data-` attr. The best would be to use the links href!

In case you  use ID you can use this:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.id;
    $("#main").load(name + ".html");
});
```

And demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uX7x5/2/)

### The **best option**:

Give the `<a>` element the correct `href` so it can be properly index by search engines. Like: `<a href='2011.html'>`. And then use this:

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sergio. I think I'm going to use the last option. I haven't named the links yet just because it's the first stage of development.

Comment: @GabrielSotero, Happy I could help! boa continuação!

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 options:

1. using ajax (asynchronous JavaScript and XML)
   you can learn that here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
2. prepend/append a iframe