# Can I change the URL without updating the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ascensor

This may seem like a dumb question. But I have no idea if it can be done. So before I start the process of making a portfolio site, I would like some pointers. Otherwise, I will just go with another design.

**My question:**

When using the ascencor.js plugin, everything on my site is in one file. I will therefor never go to a new url, like /contact or /about.

But then I wondered, what about google?

All of my content would be put inside different different classes, but in the same file:

```
<div class="floor floor-1">
    <span class="text">Floor 1</span>
</div>
<div class="floor floor-2">
    <span class="text">Floor 2</span>
</div>
```

Check the example here: http://rplambech.dk/ascencor/

So yeah, with this method, I will never change the url, so I can therefor only index one page.

Is there a way that I can change the URL without updating the site? And will I be able to go to http://rplambech.dk/ascencor/floor5 for example?

In case it's not possible, can I then at least overwrite the title of the page, each time I click to a new "page". With some PhP for example.

Or should I just go with a completely different approach? :)

Comment: What is that you want to archive? Do you want to load the content of other pages in to your `DIV` or do you want to redirect from your page to another page or do you want to tweak the URL (browser history) of your site?

Comment: I want to load the content of my pages in my DIV, and tweak the URL. No redirections.

Comment: You can try to add anchor data. Say your url is "example.com/foo.html" you could change it to "example.com/foo.html#foo5" and it will not trigger a page load. And you could check the url on load and show the contents for "foo5" in your site.

Comment: You can go with all of the nice suggesions people have made here (using # and lots of if statements). But before you re-invent the wheel, search for the term "single page application" and look at some js libraries who will make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of your question, and its comments, you're looking for the term single-page-application.

**There are many ways of doing this**, some of them make use of the history object in order to support the browser's "back" and "forward" buttons.

I'd recommend you to do a search of the term **"single page application"** and in the meantime examine some (or all) of the following frameworks (they will ease your development and make your life easier instead of dealing with `#` and nasty low-level ajax calls:

1. backbone.js
2. angularJS
3. ember.js

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using hash links, originally designed to jump to a certain div on the page are now often used to load dynamic pages on a single page

so you could link to `http://rplambech.dk/ascencor/index.html#floor5` for example

and then have some javascript like

```
var loc = location.hash.split("#")[1];
```

then

```
     if(loc == 'floor5'){
         //execute goto floor 5 code
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `history.pushState` with HTML5 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new-page-using-javascript).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
function change_my_url()
{
   history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
}
var link = document.getElementById('click');
link.addEventListener('click', change_my_url, false);
</script>
```

URL:

```
<a href="#" id='click'>Click to change url to bar.html</a>
```

Comment: Really history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");  I'll have to try this.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change the URL without going to the server.

JQuery does however have a cool page loader that will load a page.
[How to put a whole html page in a div using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155932/how-to-put-a-whole-html-page-in-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the url "/ascencor" to "/ascensor/floor5" without refreshing the page.

But you can change to "/ascensor/#floor5" (added hash sign). I suggest you try out [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) for more information.

Comment: What about the history API?

Comment: history.pushState doesn't support IE and Android, so I vote for js.

Comment: I wouldn't say you can't do it though